# artifacts at polygons

Tags: normal-map, artifacts

Artifacts appear when I connect the normal map (the presence of the texture itself is optional). the normals at the polygons are looking out.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: could you upload a file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: the file is not loaded (I generally have not seen a similar problem with anyone on the forum (((

Comment: This problem appeared due to the Mirror modifier

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28205/when-using-a-baked-normal-map-it-is-inverted-on-half-my-model

that's exactly the same mistake! but I didn’t understand how he solved the problem (English is not my native language